# React fordwardRef with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have forwarded ref using React `forwardRef` below is my code:

```
interface PropsDummy {}

const ProfileMenu = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, PropsDummy>((props, ref) => {
  console.log(ref.current);
}
```

but why this causing typescript error?

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'
```

but if I use aliasing that current object works great without typescript error

```
interface PropsDummy {}

const ProfileMenu = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, PropsDummy>((props, ref) => {
  const myRef = ref as React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  console.log(myRef.current);
}
```

how to get current object without typescript error?

thanks

Answer (score 14):

The reason it doesn't work is because the type for `ForwardedRef` is defined as:

```
type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null;
```

Or in this particular case:

```
((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>
```

Attempting to just access `.current`, without doing some type checking won't work because as you can see, the `ref` could be a function and functions do not have such a property (`current`).

It worked when you cast the object to your expected type, but note that refs can be either a function or an object (or null!), so you should be checking for this before attempting to access the `current` property.

This should work:

```
const ProfileMenu = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, PropsDummy>((props, forwardedRef) => {
  if (forwardedRef != null && typeof forwardedRef !== 'function') {
    console.log(forwardedRef.current);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App" ref={forwardedRef}>
      <h1>Hello there</h1>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: It works but is this the only solution? I am also having the same issue as poster but `forwardedRef` is being used several places in the Child component, and I don't want to check if forwardedRef is function everytime. Does anybody know another solution?

Comment: @JunKim put the value of `.current` in a `useState` and pass that state down to the child components